# Windows 10/Linux mint 18 dual boot internet problems

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, internet-connection

Recently I installed Linux mint 18 alongside Windows 10 and I messed  around with Linux for a while, but when I booted back into Windows, I couldn't connect to the internet, even though I have an internet that works on everything else in the house. I've rebooted multiple times and even reset windows, but it just keeps saying :

`couldn't connect - no connections available`

The only thing I know for certain is that it has something to do with Linux, not windows.
Please help me.